# Completeness and Incompleteness

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Through browsing questions asked in the past about Godel's completeness and imcompleteness theorems, I've come to see that the sense of completeness in both of the theorems are *different*. However, I can't see how they are different!

Does this distinction boil down to that of truth and proof? Is it the case that the completeness theorem talks about the relationship between truth and proof, while the incompleteness theorems only relate to provability?

Could someone please elaborate on the sense in which both notions of completeness are different?

Comment: They are different but linked. The *completeness* of FOL is : does the "calculus" (i.e. logical axioms + rules) have enough "power" to prove all *valid* formulae, i.e. all the formulae that are true in every interpretation ? Answer : **YES**.

Comment: The (in)-*completeness* of e.g. $\mathsf {PA}$ (first-order arithmetic) is : does the theory (Peano's axioms + logical axioms + rules) have enough "power" to prove all true (arithmetical) formulae, i.e. all the formulae that are true in the *standard* interpretation ? Answer : **NO**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the following three theorems:

**Theorem** (*Soundness*) Let $T$ be a first order theory in a given language $\mathcal L$ and let $\phi$ be a $\mathcal L$-formula. If there is a formal proof of $\phi$ from $T$ (in symbols $T \vdash \phi$), then for every model $\mathcal M$ of $T$ (i.e. $\mathcal M \models \psi$ for all $\psi \in T$) we have $\mathcal M \models \phi$.

In simpler words: If $\phi$ is provable from $T$, then it is true in every model of $T$.

**Theorem** (*Completeness*) Let $T$ be a first order theory in a given language $\mathcal L$ and let $\phi$ be a $\mathcal L$-formula. If for every model $\mathcal M$ of $T$ we have that $\mathcal M \models \phi$, then $T \vdash \phi$, i.e. there is a formal proof of $\phi$ from $T$.

In simpler words: If $\phi$ is true in every model of $T$, then there is a formal proof $T \vdash \phi$ witnessing this fact. (This is a special property of first order logic. There are other logics that don't satisfy completness.)

These two theorems combined are very promissing: In a sense *Soundness* says that everything provable is true. On the other hand *Completeness* says that everything *universally true* always has a formal proof. Great! However, there is one case not handled yet. What if $\phi$ is true in some models of $T$ and false in other models of $T$? Such a formula $\phi$ can't have a formal proof and also its negation $\neg \phi$ cannot be proved. It was hoped that this doesn't occur for nice theories $T$. For example, if $T$ is complete, this never occurs.

A (somewhat shocking - at least at that time -) result due to Gödel says that any *natural* theory $T$ has a formula $\phi$ such that $T \not \vdash \phi$ and $T \not \vdash \neg \phi$. In other words: If $T$ is consistent, then there are models $\mathcal M, \mathcal N$, such that $\mathcal M \models T \cup \{ \phi \}$ and $\mathcal N \models T \cup \{ \neg \phi \}$. More precisely:

**Theorem** (*Incompleteness*) Let $T$ be a recursive enumerable, consistent theory that can interpret *Peano Arithmetics*. Then there is a statement $\phi$ such that $T \not \vdash \phi$ and $T \not \vdash \neg \phi$.

In fact, this is true for $\phi \equiv \operatorname{Con}(T)$. Hence there is a *true* statement that $T$ cannot decide.

People often emphasize how bad this result is when it comes to Hilbert's program or the quest for a formal foundation of mathematics. While their concern is justified to some extend, I personally view the *Incompleteness Theorem* in another light: The proof of the *Incompleteness Theorem* boils down to a (very clever) fixed point argument that works, precisely because $T$ is recursively enumerable and can code formal proofs. Take either of those properties away and it doesn't work anymore. To me this says that consistent theories of a decent proof-theoretical complexity can't be coded as very simple subsets of $\mathbb N$. In other words: Any reasonable coding of such a theory has a nontrivial Turing degree. From a modern point of view this isn't surprising at all - it's to be expected.

Finally, let us compare these three theorems in light of your question. *Soundness* and *Completeness* tell us that our notion of formal proof is *correct* (both mathematically and philosophically). We can prove precisely those statements that $T$ implies (model theoretic) and that's exactly what we want.

*Incompleteness*, on the other hand, tells us, that all consistent, sufficiently complex (in terms of proof theory) theories that can be enumerated by a Turing machine have a (true) statement that they do not decide. Or - in other words - any consistent, sufficiently complex *and complete* theory cannot be enumerated by a Turing machine. This really says that any reasonable coding of such a theory must be pretty complex.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is great. I would like to ask two questions: what is Con(T)? and, is the continuum hypothesis one of these "Godel statements" refered to in the incompleteness theorems? Or is the undecideability of CH different again?

Comment: Regarding your first question: $\operatorname{Con}(T)$ is a coding of the statement "$T \text{ is consistent}$". So the statement says that $T$ (even though it is consistent) cannot prove its own consistence. It was hoped (by Hilbert and others) that a foundation for mathematics would prove its own consistency. Regarding your second question: $\operatorname{CH}$ is indeed a statement that the theory $\operatorname{ZFC}$ cannot decide. However, the technique to prove this fact is entirely different to the approach from the above proof theoretical statements.

Comment: Thanks for your great answers Stefan. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @User0112358 You're most welcome!

Comment: One more question. Truth in the first sense I understand: we require the statement to be true in all models. What is the truth in the sense of Godels theorems? What do we mean when we say that there is an undecideable statement which is TRUE? Do we mean true in all models again?

Comment: @User0112358 In general, this is a very delicate point. Luckily, in this case, it's easy. We assume (in our meta-theory) that $T$ is a consistent theory. In this sense $\operatorname{Con}(T)$ is true. However, since $T$ cannot prove its own consistency, there are models of $T \cup \{ \neg \operatorname{Con}(T) \}$, i.e. models that believe $T$ is inconsistent. This seems contradictory, but it's not. An informal justification of this situation is that models of $T \cup \{ \neg \operatorname{Con}(T) \}$ are *non-standard* and therefore disagree with us on seemingly basic facts.

Comment: @User0112358 I'd also like to say that I very much enjoyed this brief exchange. You're asking the right questions and I'm glad if I can help you to get through this with hopefully less struggle than it was for me a couple of years ago.

Comment: I think this is the point that has had be confused since I started learning about the foundations of mathematics; I am glad (since it has confused me for so long) to hear it is delicate. Thanks for helping me clear it up.

Comment: How do you prove completeness, given the requirement of "in every model"?

Answer (score 2):

The completeness theorem for first order logic is a general statement about first order languages and associated deductive rules that says if something is true in every model of a theory, then it's a provable consequence of that theory. That is, we do not end up with theories that are consistent but have no model, in which case we would be able to justifiably consider our notion of "model" to be inadequate to capture *all of* the theories we want to study. The key here is it's about a relation between first order languages and models of theories in those languages.

The second notion of completeness is a property of a theory, not of an entire deductive system, and we need not even talk about models to describe it. A theory $T$ is complete iff for every sentence $\varphi$, $T\vdash\varphi$ or $T\vdash\neg\varphi$. This is the sense of "complete" in Goedel's famous theorem.

Hopefully this should make it clear that these are different things; to say that first order logic is complete in the *second* sense would be gibberish because first order logic is not a first order theory. Likewise, to say that the theory of the real numbers is complete in the *first* sense is also gibberish, because the theory of real numbers is not a deductive system.

Answer (score 1):

To put it real short: Godel's completeness result is about (first-order) logic itself, and his incompleteness result is about arithmetic.

One way to put the results is: we can axiomatize all of (first-order) logic itself, but we cannot axiomatize all of arithmetic.